# Coins Gained on Moving - Scythe

Tags: scythe

When using the move action, do I gain coins in an equal number of the number of units I decide to move (up to 2)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The / means "or".  You may move up to two units or you may take the amount of coins on your play mat.